# Releasing CFStringRef after casting to NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory, memory-leaks

I'm converting an Objective-C function which casts a CFStringRef to an NSString like so (where FSEventStreamCopyDescription returns a CFStringRef):

```
return (NSString *)FSEventStreamCopyDescription(eventStream);
```

However, upon analyzing my application I'm told that this will cause a 'potential leak', due to the absence of a CFRelease call. I'm attempting to rewrite this function to avoid any leaks. What's the correct way of handling this? I've provided two possibilities (both of which could be incorrect):

Option A:

```
CFStringRef ref = FSEventStreamCopyDescription(eventStream);
NSString *desc = [(NSString *)ref copy];
CFRelease(ref);

return [desc autorelease];
```

Option B:

```
CFStringRef ref = FSEventStreamCopyDescription(eventStream);
NSString *desc = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:(NSString *)ref];
CFRelease(ref);

return [desc autorelease];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Casting does not do anything to the object. A cast only tells the compiler “this is really a `_____`”.

It also doesn't do anything to the memory management rules. You still have an object that you obtained from a function that follows the CF rules and contains Copy in its name. Therefore, you own that object; therefore, you are responsible for releasing it.

It is not the name of the class that matters; toll-free bridging means that a CFString *is* an NSString. What matters is what rules the function or method you got the object from follows ([CF rules](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html) or [Foundation rules](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)), and whether you obey them.

Both Options A and B solve the problem, but with excess complexity.

The copy and release in Option A achieves nothing. You already copied it; making another copy does not change the situation. It only wastes time, both yours and the user's.

The `initWithString:` (or `stringWithString:`) of Option B also achieves nothing. You already have a CFString, and a CFString is an NSString, so you don't need to create an NSString. Ultimately, this is equivalent to Option A.

@kubi's answer is the best so far, but bears one improvement:

```
return [NSMakeCollectable(FSEventStreamCopyDescription(eventStream)) autorelease];
```

With this change, the code will work correctly under garbage collection, where `autorelease` does nothing. Meanwhile, under retain/release rules, `NSMakeCollectable` does nothing. Either way, your ownership will be released/collected at the appropriate time.

Comment: I'll mark this as correct for the detailed explanation. I learned something, thanks a lot.

Comment: @peter, what if one is using ARC and writing 'autorelease' is not an option? In my case I'm storing the result of an `ABRecordCopyValue` into my own subclass of `NSObject`. Can I ignore the warning?

Comment: @entonio: Under ARC, if you're storing a reference to a CF object into an instance variable, you should use `CFBridgingRelease` or the equivalent `__bridge_transfer` cast.

Comment: thank you @peter, I've confimed that, unless one does what you say, there will be a leak. I've settled for `CFBridgingRelease` since it's easier on my eyes.

Answer (score 2):

Either will work.  My preference is option A.

You can also use NSString's [-stringWithString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-stringWithString_): method which returns you a string that doesn't need auto releasing.

```
CFStringRef ref = FSEventStreamCopyDescription(eventStream);
NSString *desc = [NSString stringWithString: (NSString *)ref];
CFRelease(ref);

return desc;
```

Answer (score 2):

Third option:

```
return [(NSString *)FSEventStreamCopyDescription(eventStream) autorelease];
```

Comment: Interestingly this still triggers the Analyzer warning about Leaks. I was under the impression that CFStrings had to use CFRelease, but I assume the above logic is sound due to toll-free bridging?

Comment: This solution works in a non-GC environment, but is not effective with GC (where autorelease is essentially a no-op).